# How to read a tab delimited file in R when data row contains an extra separator at end of line?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a file but it has an annoying problem.  The header has 5 columns but the data has 6 due to an extra tab character at the end of line for data rows.  It confused R and so it put the item code as row name and all data are not shifted by one position.

```
> items <- read.csv("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", sep = "\t")
> items[1,]
               item_code item_name display_level selectable sort_sequence
AA0 All items - old base         0          TRUE          2            NA
> row.names(items[1,])
[1] "AA0"
```

Any idea how to fix this?  If I specify row.names = NULL, it would read in the item code into a "row.names" column but everything is still shifted.

```
> items <- read.csv("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", sep = "\t", row.names = NULL)
> items[1,]
  row.names            item_code item_name display_level selectable sort_sequence
1       AA0 All items - old base         0          TRUE          2            NA
```

Comment: Skip the header and add it in later? Specify the number of columns to read?

Comment: You could specify the `colClasses` if you know the number of columns.  `res1 <- read.table('http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item', sep="\t", colClasses=c(rep('character',2), 'integer', 'logical', 'numeric', NULL), row.names=NULL);
 names(res1) <- names(res1)[-1]; res2 <- res1[-ncol(res1)]`

Comment: I'd like to see an Answer using httr's content function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can try to read in the file without the first line and then add the headers in later.

Something like:

```
read.table("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", 
           header = FALSE, skip = 1, 
           col.names = c(
             scan("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", 
                  what = "", n = 5), "XXXXX"), 
           sep = "\t")[-6]
```

The `[-6]` is to drop the column of `NA` values.

Here's what I get with the above:

```
head(
  read.table("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", 
             header = FALSE, skip = 1, 
             col.names = c(
               scan("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item", 
                    what = "", n = 5), "XXXXX"), 
             sep = "\t")[-6])
# Read 5 items
#   item_code                                          item_name display_level
# 1       AA0                               All items - old base             0
# 2      AA0R Purchasing power of the consumer dollar - old base             0
# 3       SA0                                          All items             0
# 4      SA0E                                             Energy             1
# 5     SA0L1                                All items less food             1
# 6    SA0L12                    All items less food and shelter             1
#   selectable sort_sequence
# 1       TRUE             2
# 2       TRUE           399
# 3       TRUE             1
# 4       TRUE           374
# 5       TRUE           358
# 6       TRUE           361
```

Comment: Exact same issue from another bls site - what is it with that site? Upvote